# DataGrid Lostfocus event triggers every action on the DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to update the values of the DataGrid only when we come out of the control. So to achieve this i used LostFocus event of the datagrid. But this event triggering every action of the datagrid. For example when i clik on the cell to edit it is triggering.

Control ctrl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as Control; gives always null. :(

```
DataGrid simpleTable = new DataGrid();
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        textColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(DefaultSize.Width/2, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);

        simpleTable.Style = tableStyle;
        textColumn.Binding = new Binding("Value");
        textColumn.ElementStyle = elementStyle;
      //  textColumn.Width = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
        simpleTable.Columns.Add(textColumn);

        simpleTable.ItemsPanel = template;
        simpleTable.LostFocus += _dataGridLostFocus;

private void _dataGridLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as Control;
        if (ctrl.Parent != null && ctrl.Parent.GetType() != typeof(DataGridCell))
            MessageBox.Show("outside!");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the DataGrid looses the Focus because the inner control does receive it.

Please try [IsKeyboardFocusWithin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithinchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) either by using the property or with this event.

Answer (score 0):

When `DataGridCell` loses focus, it triggers the `DataGrid`Lost Focus event. You need to handle the cells event.

Throw this style in your `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_LostFocus"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Then in your code behind

```
private void DataGridCell_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

EDIT: Since you are creating your DataGrid dynamically, here is how you would style the DataGrid's cells to subscribe to the lost focus event above.

Create a delagate

```
 private delegate void Lost_Focus_Delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
```

Then in your DataGrid generation.

```
 Style style = new Style
 {
     TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell)
 };

 style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(LostFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(new Lost_Focus_Delegate(this.DataGridCell_LostFocus))));

 dataGrid.CellStyle = style;
```

Comment: I just realized your DataGrid is created dynamically. The theory remains, you will just have to style the DataGrid's DataGridCell dynamically.